# How can I make trapezoid-shaped wood board (beveled edges)?

Tags: woodworking

The reason why I want this is somewhat difficult to explain.  I basically am looking for moulding-sized planks that have a trapezoid shape like this:

[image]

That's the best trapezoid shape I could find, but it's going to be as slim as the moulding/trim you'd find around your door or along your floor and wall.  Is there a tool that can create such beveled edges on a plank of wood as thin as a plank of moulding?

Edit: I wasn't clear on this, but I am looking for lengths up to 7 feet long, 2 1/2 inches wide, and 1/4 to 1/2 inch thick.  I want to miter the edges so that, looking at it dead center, it will look like the below.  Look at it as if it's a moulding profile.  I am basically going to be creating my own moulding for a project.

Comment: can you put dimensions to your diagram?

Comment: I put the approximate dimensions in my question H 7', W 2 1/2", D 1/2".  They may change once I really size everything up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry. My first answer mis-understoood the question. Based on the updated question, there are many ways to create a shape of the desired profile, based on what tools you have or can find/buy/etc.

- Rip the edges with an angled tablesaw blade.
- A handheld power (circular) saw, with the blade at an angle. A fence will help you get a straight edge.
- A jointer.
- A handheld power jointer.
- A hand plane. A good craftsman with a sharp jointer plane can do this easily.
- A router table.
- A handheld router.
- A millwork shop can easily turn this profile out, so you can always buy it ready made, for a price.
- If you have a friend with any of the above power tools, I'll bet they can be bought off for the price of a pizza.

Very much depends on what tools you have, how much money you want to spend. You can use it to justify buying a specific tool, if you have a use for one of the tools I've mentioned. They are all useful.

A tablesaw or a router are both terribly useful tools, but if this is a one time job and you have no interest in woodworking, then I'd look for a friend who can help you out. If you insist on doing it yourself, and might have an occasional use for a hand held circular saw, then go that route. A circular saw will be often enough of use even to someone who is not an avid woodworker.

Attach your board to a straight piece of wood to use as a fence. Then angle the blade, and rip the edge as you want it. I'll argue this is the cheapest solution that will give you a good edge. (A hand held jointer plane might be even cheaper, since you can get them quite inexpensively from an antique shop. But a jointer plane will take some practice to do this job well.)

Comment: Based on the mention of molding, I think he's talking about a trapezoidal cross-section, in which case a a miter saw won't work.

Comment: That's correct.  I wasn't clear on that and updated my question.

Comment: I replaced my answer with a more accurate one. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

A table saw usually has a blade bevel setting.

Assuming your angles are 45 degrees, I'd do it like this:

1. Buy stock.  Hopefully, you'll buy it at an acceptable thickness. Otherwise, you'll have to rip it.
2. Rip stock to thickness - measure from the blade to the guide.  Lock the guide, rip.
3. Count fingers.  If 10, proceed to step 4.  Otherwise, you should have used a pusher.
4. Set Bevel to 45 degrees.  Position guide so that you are cutting just inside the corner. Rip.
5. Without changing the bevel, turn the board around so that you're bevelling the other side. Now is the time to set the guide to the appropriate width of your finished product.

Protip: Sacrifice a couple of feet of your stock.  Test your settings on this scrap piece before you rip the entire batch.

I doubt however, that your saw will cut a 45 degree bevel.  You may have to settle for 30.  The other alternative, if you insist on 45 is to rip a wedge that you can clamp to the saw table to give the appropriate angle.

Comment: Or, lacking a tablesaw, a router with a bevel bit.  Or a handplane and lots of sweat :)